# iChat with Yahoo Messenger keeps prompting about the same buddy requests

Tags: ichat, yahoo

I have iChat set up with the Yahoo Messenger protocol. Every time I log in, or suspend/resume my machine, it prompts me to respond to the same 3 Yahoo Messenger buddy requests. I always hit "decline", dismissing the dialogs, but it doesn't seem to stick. Is there a way to fix this?

This is iChat v6.0.1, with Lion

Comment: I have the same problem except it happens in Adium.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the problem lays in the chat protocol between the Mac and Yahoo.

The only solution I've found is to log on with a Window's machine using the latest Y!M client and doing the decline/ignore there.

I was up to 15 messages requests between my two acts every time I woke my Mac from sleep. Going to the Yahoo client on Windows cleared this up entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same sort of problem, but this time it was on a macbook pro and iMessage  that I kept getting a request (From oratoracallyshirley!) to be a "buddy". I went to my pc desktop, logged onto IE and my homepage (which is Yahoo), clicked on "Mail", then opened the "chat" button, clicked on oratoracallyshirley, deleted and blocked it, then went back to my macbook pro and Hey Presto, no "requests for buddies"!

Comment: clicked on what ?